# SharePoint Online Document Details Pane Not Refreshed when using Next/Prev Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

SharePoint online details pane not refreshing metadata when using next/prev button.

When navigating back and forth documents it shows the same metadata for all documents

Any ideas why its not refreshing the metadata

Thanks

Comment: Where's the next/prev buttons shown in library? I think you need to to select the document in order to see it's details.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem in my test environment.

**It is recommended that you do the following:**

1. Clear the browser cache, and then sign in page again to perform the operation.
2. When clicking the **Previous/Next** button, if the Document Detailed Panel still does not refresh the metadata. Please click the **"Exit" icon(X)** in the upper right corner, and then click the **"Exclamation point" icon(!)**.

[image]

Comment: I can click on icon but what I'm asking how to resolve without clicking each and every time, I have multiple PDF's to work on ex: more than 500+ files to check PDF content and edit the metadata, so each time clicking on icon is not a solution

Comment: Hi, Arun. Thanks for your reply. So far, this is the best solution. I would suggest you submit a feedback via User Voice
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks, I have raised a ticket with Microsoft, will let you know if they say something

Comment: Hi, Arun. Okay, I hope the problem can be solved perfectly. Have a nice day!